# Using controller for association to render different partials depending on the belongs_to object type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

My question was if Post has_many Comments, and I just want to update a comment, should I do that in the Post, or Comments controllers. I just watched the Railscasts on Polymorphic Associations and saw that he does it in the comments controller.

But what if I need to render a different partial depending on which commentable type it was called by? In other words, if a Post comment is being added, then render partial _post_comment. If a Video comment is being added, then render partial _video_comment, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep the logic in the comments controller.

You can render the partial depending on the linked object doing:

```
  case @comment.commentable
  when Post
     render ...
  when Video
     render ...
  else
     ...
  end
```